# A question about cofibrations

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cofibrations

Let $(X, A)$ be a cofibration, with $X$ compactly generated. This is equivalent to the fact that $A$ is a NDR of $X$, i.e., there exist two functions $\phi \colon X \rightarrow I$ e $H \colon X \times I \rightarrow X$ such that $A = \phi^{-1}(\{0\})$, $H(x, 0) = x$ and $H(a, t) = a$ for every $x \in X, a \in A, t \in I$, and $H(x, 1) \in A$ for every $x \in \phi^{-1}([0, 1))$. We call $U := \phi^{-1}([0, 1))$. The definition does not imply that $A$ is a (strong) deformation retract of $U$, because it is not necessary that $H(U \times I) \subset U$. Actually, in Strom's book ''Modern classical homotopy theory'', theorem 5.20 p. 104, it is stated that $A$ is a deformation retract of $U$, but I didn't manage to prove that the function $H$, defined in problem 5.21 p. 105, satisfies $H(U \times I) \subset U$. My question is the following.

*Question*: If $(X, A)$ is a NDR pair and $X$ is compactly generated, is it true that $H$ and $\phi$ can be chosen in such a way that $A$ is a (strong) deformation retract of U? (This implies that $(X, A)$ is a good pair in the sense of Hatcher's book.) If not, what is a counter-example? Moreover, if the answer is negative, is there a cofibration $(X, A)$ such that $A$ is not a (strong) deformation retract of any neighborhood, even different from $\phi^{-1}([0, 1))$?

Actually, in May's book ''The geometry of iterated loop spaces'', definition A.1 p. 85, an NDR-pair is called *strong* if $\phi(H(x, t)) < 1$ when $\phi(x) < 1$, which is equivalent to $H(U \times I) \subset U$. Therefore my question can be formulated in the following way: is every NDR-pair (at least when $X$ is compactly generated) strong? If not, what is a counter-example?

Comment: P.S. In problem 5.21 p. 105 of Strom's book, I think the definition of $U$ is not correct. It is stated that $U = (r_{1}(\cdot, 1))^{-1}(A)$, but in this case $U$ is closed. It should be $U = \phi^{-1}([0, 1))$. If $x \in U$, then $r_{1}(x, 1) \in A$, because $r_{2}(x, 1) > 0$, but not vice-versa.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854281/good-pair-vs-cofibration

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547820/neighborhood-deformation-retracts-vs-cofibrations/3550166?noredirect=1#3550166